# Edit HTML inside text/template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got multiple **text/template** scripts in my code, I want to be able to change the **h1** tag in all of them using javascript *(Jquery)*

```
<script type="text/template">
    <h1>This should be replaced</h1>
    <p>Testing 123</p>
</script>
```

I don't want to create a new element from this template, I want to change the actual content of the template.

Here's what I've tried so far, which sadly doesn't return any results.

```
console.log($("script[type='text/template']"));
```

Really grateful for pointers!

Comment: You want to replace **<h1>This should be replaced</h1>** with some tag ?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using. It works fine as a fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/kaminasw/bwns89Lq/

Comment: It does return a result in the console for me: https://jsfiddle.net/6L6mt7ta/

Comment: `$("script[type='text/template']").get(0)`? This will return html element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `h1` element is not part of your `DOM` you can create a new element, add your HTML to that element, manipulate it (using jquery) and then put the result back into the original `script` element:

```js
t = $("script[type='text/template']")
container = $('<div/>').html(t.html())
container.find('h1').replaceWith('<h2>new content</h2>')
t.html(container.html())

console.log($("script[type='text/template']").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template">
    <h1>This should be replaced</h1>
    <p>Testing 123</p>
</script>
```

Comment: @Abhitalks correct :) you are welcome to voteup my original answer

Comment: @Connum That's awkward.. I tried the code over and over and just now realized that it DOES return results, I ran the code before the document was fully loaded. So sorry, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

you can get all h1's with:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
```

and then you loop through it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = "text";
}
```

Comment: content of `text/template` elements is not part of the DOM so you can't use `getElementsByTagName` here.